# Dynamically update filter content, in Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a markdown filter and the content of `component.doc` is going to be updated via a websocket.  However when the update event is fired and the scope’s component is updated, the filtered content stays the same.

How can I dynamically update the `v-html` in the following code.

```
// Filter
Vue.filter('markdown', (value) => marked(value))

// Usage
<div v-html="component.doc | markdown"></div>
```

Comment: Could you post an example fiddle or more code. what you have should work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Vue v2 ? If so, then it is impossible to do what you want:

> Vue 2.x filters can only be used inside mustache interpolations and v-bind expressions (the latter supported since 2.1.0), because filters are primarily designed for text transformation purposes. For more complex data transforms in other directives, you should use Computed properties instead.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Filters